# How to Create one .sln for multiple .slns file using SVN and Tortoise SVN

Tags: svn, visual-studio-2012, tortoisesvn

I am new to version Control SVN. 
I have 3 projects with the following Folder structure.

- Projects

  - ProjectA

    - Trunk

      - eproj.sln
  - Projectb

    - Trunk

      - eproj1.sln
  - Projectc

    - Trunk

      - eproj2.sln

Now I want all 3 sln file combines to one sln file when open in visual studio 2012 it open all 3 projects so that I don't have to open 3 sln file

Comment: You may need to have one solution with 3 projects.i don't think you can nest solutions and have them opening VS. But you can set then go to run at the same time

Comment: I did that but than I couldn't commit from Visual Studio to the respective branch

Comment: Yes VS integration falls down at that point but you can use tortoiseSVN to do your commits.

Comment: Can you help achieving it ? Again I wanted to just create One SLn file that open each project and commit happens respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create new empty solution. Make initial commit to SVN or git. Import the first project into the solution. Test it on its own,  then commit. Import next project into solution test each project separately then commit. Note you are not importing any of the existing sln files!

Now modify the Solution properties. You can change it from starting a single project to starting multiple projects - you will need to select them. Now all will run when you press (ctrl +) F5.

If all goes well then SVN integration will still work.

Comment: I used the blank solution , Problem is , the projects by default is in the URL while when I create empty project and Commit , it saves to my local machine.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are saying there. Is it that the empty solution was not configured the same as if you started a Web project or a new website solution? If so then you could do that as your first stage and manually import the contents of your first project. Select each project in the solution explorer and view properties (Alt + Enter) check the details on the Web tab.

Comment: @UrvilShah - Did you resolve your multi-project solution?

Comment: I did solve my problem , but using another alternative I created an empty solution file and committed to the SVN server and by adding each project except removing /editing sln file by removing the root location    I committed individual project. but in this I am facing an issue . My history with each file has been lost. You have any idea how to recover history associated with it.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't expecting to be able to retain the history. But you should have the old repository and the separate new repository. Disjointed but accessible

Comment: That I do. Thanks for your help .